# Keeping dodge position in boxplot passed to plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, boxplot

I have a regular `boxplot` in `ggplot2`:

```
# working example
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl=as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  mutate(vs=as.factor(vs)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(y=mpg, x=cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour=vs))
```

It looks like this:
[image]

However, when I create an object and pass it to `plotly`, I lose the dodge position:

```
library(plotly)
mtcars_boxplot <-
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl=as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  mutate(vs=as.factor(vs)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(y=mpg, x=cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour=vs))

mtcars_boxplot %>%
  ggplotly()
```

It looks like this:
[image]

I tried to add `position=position_dodge()` & `position=position_dodge2()` but none of them worked:

```
library(plotly)

mtcars_boxplot <-
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl=as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  mutate(vs=as.factor(vs)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(y=mpg, x=cyl)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour=vs), position=position_dodge2())

mtcars_boxplot %>%
  ggplotly()
```

What should I do to keep the dodge position like the first plot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/679), add `layout(boxmode = "group")`

```
library(plotly)
mtcars_boxplot %>%
  ggplotly() %>%
  layout(boxmode = "group")
```

Comment: This kind of works for me (prints out side by side boxes) but, I get a warning ``'layout' objects don't have these attributes: 'boxmode'`. The box width also becomes quite narrow.

Comment: @steveb the warning should be fine as they mentioned [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/994). The box width should become narrower to account for the missing level in _cyl=8_ which is the desired behavior in this case, actually `plotly` handles this better than `ggplot2` see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3345)"

Comment: I forgot to mention, I was plotting my own data and have had an issue with the box width when using `ggplotly`, however, when I just use `ggplot` or `plotly` (directly, not with `ggplotly`), I don't have the box width issue. I may need to create a new SO question if I am to get an answer. I need to do some experimenting on my particular issue before posting.

Comment: The issue I am running into is happening when I put my 6 plots into a 3x2 subplot. This doesn't happen in straight `ggplot` but it does happen when using `plotly`.

Comment: Has there been a solution to solve the with issue yet? I am still experiencing it.